# Practical drawbacks of primitive Decorators

Tags: java, c++, decorator

Inspired by `Decorator` pattern but sure that the gist of the pattern can be implemented with less complexity, I've produced two quick snippets, in C++11 and Java respectively.

Decorator.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Box {

public:
    virtual string getDescription()
    {
        return "A box";
    }
};

class BoxDecorator : public Box {
    Box* wrapee;

public:
    BoxDecorator(Box* box)
    {
        wrapee = box;
    }
    string getDescription()
    {
        return wrapee->getDescription();
    }
};

class RedBox : public BoxDecorator {

public:
    RedBox(Box* box)
        : BoxDecorator(box)
    {
    }

    string getDescription()
    {
        return BoxDecorator::getDescription() + ", red-colored";
    }
};

class BigBox : public BoxDecorator {

public:
    BigBox(Box* box)
        : BoxDecorator(box)
    {
    }

    string getDescription()
    {
        return BoxDecorator::getDescription() + ", big-sized";
    }
};

class StripedBox : public BoxDecorator {

public:
    StripedBox(Box* box)
        : BoxDecorator(box)
    {
    }

    string getDescription()
    {
        return BoxDecorator::getDescription() + ", with several stripes around it";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Box* sampleBox = new StripedBox(new RedBox(new BigBox(new Box())));
    cout << sampleBox->getDescription() << endl;
}
```

Decorator.java:

```
class Box {

 public Box() {

 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return "A box";
 }

}

class BoxDecorator extends Box {

 Box boxToBeDecorated;

 public BoxDecorator(Box box) {
  boxToBeDecorated = box;
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return boxToBeDecorated.getDescription();
 }


}

class RedBox extends BoxDecorator {

 public RedBox(Box box) {
  super(box);
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return super.getDescription() + ", red-colored";
 }
}

class BigBox extends BoxDecorator {

 public BigBox(Box box) {
  super(box);
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return super.getDescription() + ", big-sized";
 }
}

class StripedBox extends BoxDecorator {

 public StripedBox(Box box) {
  super(box);
 }

 public String getDescription() {
  return super.getDescription() + ", with several stripes around it";
 }
}

public class Decorator {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  Box sampleBox = new StripedBox(new RedBox(new BigBox(new Box())));
  System.out.println(sampleBox.getDescription());

 }
}
```

Both are generating valid "A box, big-sized, red-colored, with several stripes around it" output. So it's not that complexity of the language forces us [to use interfaces or abstract classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#Examples) in case of Java, for example.

Which, then, are practical drawbacks of these stripped-off "Decorators"?

Answer (score 1):

Here you inherit implementation of Box. This takes memory, could cause problems (e.g. a constructor could have side effects). There is no reason of inheriting Box. In addition, the number of possible combinations of decorator chains grows exponentially if inheritance is used.

Comment: A bit curious about how memory is affected when inheriting Decorator from Box. I imagine a case in which Box is very memory-heavy, and then Decorator instances get all that bloat inside them which is horrible for performance. Is that more or less close to your point?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. All member fields of a super class occupy memory even if they are obviously not used.